# how to fetch multiple data from mysql after joining multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me out in fetching into rows.

```
$results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT base.*, charge.id, cloud.id, mask.id, sense.id.* 
      FROM base INNER JOIN charge ON base.id = charge.id 
                INNER JOIN cloud ON base.id = cloud.id 
                INNER JOIN mask ON base.id = mask.id 
                INNER JOIN sense ON base.id = sense.id ");
```

I'm getting an error a `{Error: Unknown table 'sense.id'}`. Even though there is an error.

How to correct this?

Comment: Where is the join for `sense` table if it is a table?

Comment: You select `sense.id.*` which means select every column from table  `sense.id`. Change it to `sense.*` if you want to select everything from table sense or `sense.id` if you want to select just the `id` column.

Answer (score 0):

please try sense.* inplace of sense.id.*

```
"SELECT base.*, charge.id, cloud.id, mask.id, sense.* 
      FROM base INNER JOIN charge ON base.id = charge.id 
                INNER JOIN cloud ON base.id = cloud.id 
                INNER JOIN mask ON base.id = mask.id 
                INNER JOIN sense ON base.id = sense.id "
```

Comment: i replaced that * sense.id with sense* and now it's showing " Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object  "

how to correct that??